# Writing text and numeric variable to text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
ahk_second_number = 4
file = open("D:/Arch (all versions)/Work/SCIPE/Data upload script/count_txt_file/patient_count.txt", "w")
file.write("0\n%" % str(ahk_second_number))
file.close() #This close() is important
```

I want to get a  `patient_count.txt` which will contain 0 on first line and content of `ahk_second_number` variable on second line.

It gives me error:

```
runfile('D:/del/untitled0.py', wdir='D:/del')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-23b229935f25>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/del/untitled0.py', wdir='D:/del')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/del/untitled0.py", line 3, in <module>
    file.write("0\n%" % str(ahk_second_number))

ValueError: incomplete format
```

**Question:** How to correct my code above so it will give me `patient_count.txt` that I need (described above)?

Comment: `%` should be `%d` in the format string.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. `file.write("0\n%d" % ahk_second_number)` worked.

Comment: Railing slightly off-topic but `# This close() is important` is much less of an issue with Python. Look it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code line instead the one you stated:

```
file.write("0\n%d" % ahk_second_number)
```

You were missing the format of your variable you are trying to write. `%d` means it writes integer values, hence no need to convert your integer to string.

You can get some more details about formatting when writing variables [here](https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting). Also you can read about formatting in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting).

Comment: You are right. Added an explanation to the solution.

Comment: It is not a *brilliant* question, especially when the OP seems adept in C and the cause is clear enough to close-as-typo, but still: "Try this `insert code here`" answers are not useful to *anyone*. (That link is also useful, but you might want to point to the official documentation ) (And welcome to the 2K Crowd. Enjoy your new privileges!)

Comment: That's why I added the explanation you suggested. I agree with you.

Comment: @usr2564301 I tried to find a link to the official documentation but couldn't find any page mentioning the `%d` so far.

Comment: Ha, you're right. As it seems (officially? unofficially?) deprecated, it was kind of hidden. Here you go: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting - you could edit it in, or just leave your link as it explains enough.

Comment: Great! Good catch. I added that link as well.